# Photoshop CS5 - Change Color of Selecting/Highlighting Text

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When you highlight/select a text it highlights it in Black. Can I change it from Black highlight to a different color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to change the highlight. The app automatically chooses the highest contrast value it can for the highlight. Its generally black on light backgrounds and white on dark backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I spent half the day trying to find a way to change the highlight text color. :(